# Sencha command not found although it's added automatically in the .bash_profile by the installer

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I came across a lot of similar threads but none helped me to fix my issue. I am trying ot build sencha 2.2.1 application through the cmd commands, so [downloaded the SDK](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/download/) and [installed the cmd environment](http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download), now trying to generate my first project, so I cd to the sdk folder and try to create new project:

```
sencha generate app MyApp ../MyApp
```

but sencha command is not found, the classic message we usually got and first assumption is that this command is missing in the `.bash_profile`, but it seems not, here is the `.bash_profile` file content from my user root directory:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
export PATH=/Users/Malloc/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342:$PATH

export SENCHA_CMD_3_0_0="/Users/Malloc/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342"
```

But, `echo $PATH` doesn't display the sencha path, so I assume there is somthing missing but don't knwo how to fix. Here is the `echo $PATH`:

```
/Users/Malloc/repos/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.4/bin:/Users/Malloc/repos/ringojs/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

I opened new session in my terminal but still getting the same error:

```
command not found: sencha
```

Does anyone run the same issue? how can I fix that? Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to fix it, I am using zsh and seems the path variables need to be updated in the `.zshrc` file.

```
cd root_user_directory
open -e .zshrc
```

Same exports added by the installer on the `.bash_profile` file need to be added to `.zshrc` file:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
export PATH=/Users/Malloc/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342:$PATH

export SENCHA_CMD_3_0_0="/Users/Malloc/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342"
```

Start new zsh session and now the `sencha` command works correctly.